# Java Spring Boot - user handling logic?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication

I am fairly new to Java and Spring Boot. I've started to try and map out the various functions and parameters.

1. Please check the logic -- if user exists, etc.. error message handling -- I'd like to create a clean response so

I am basically asking -- is there a solid way of doing login handling -- user reg etc.. -- pseudo code wise -- should I check for the user here, do a try catch error here. Rather than re-inventing the wheel –

....

```
BasicObject obj = null
obj.message = "Logging User"
obj.result = "success"
obj.data = response;
```

ok so in reference to the methods

login (is the logic correct, need to add session handling)
logout (is the logic correct, need to add session handling)
forgot (is the logic correct, need to send an email out)
edit (is the logic correct, more so - how will this be different to the register method - use saveAndFlush -- would it be a new Account?)
register (is the logic correct, need to send an email out)

An answer in psesdo code like -- "at the login step your try/catch methods are fine or you could do this first first to improve the dryness of the code.. -- break up the red/edit to share similar inheritance"

This is what my current code base looks like -- I essentially want to power a reactjs build with an api -- so in terms of architecture -- the /api would be a get service -- the other's are post's from forms.

--

```
package controller;


import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.tomcat.util.log.SystemLogHandler;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import domain.Account;
import repo.AccountRepository;


@RestController
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/api", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> index(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="admin1") String name) throws Exception {
            Account acc = accountRepository.findByUsername(name);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(acc, HttpStatus.OK);
    }




    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(
            @RequestParam(value="email", required=false, defaultValue="email") String email,
            @RequestParam(value="password", required=false, defaultValue="password") String password, 
            HttpServletRequest request
            ) throws  Exception {
            List<Account> acc = accountRepository.findByEmail(email);

            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("user", acc);

            System.out.println("logged>>>"+acc);
            System.out.println("session>>>"+session);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(acc, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> logout(
            HttpServletRequest request
            ) throws  Exception {

            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            List<Account> acc = (List<Account>) session.getAttribute("user");

            session.removeAttribute("user");            

            System.out.println("logout>>>"+acc);
            System.out.println("session>>>"+session);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(acc, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/forgot", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> forgot(
            @RequestParam(value="email", required=false, defaultValue="email") String email
            ) throws  Exception {
            List<Account> acc = accountRepository.findByEmail(email);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(acc, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> edit(
            @RequestParam(value="username", required=false, defaultValue="username") String username,
            @RequestParam(value="password", required=false, defaultValue="password") String password,
            @RequestParam(value="email", required=false, defaultValue="email") String email
            ) throws  Exception {
            Account acc = accountRepository.findByUsername(username);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(acc, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> register(
            @RequestParam(value="username", required=false, defaultValue="username") String username,
            @RequestParam(value="password", required=false, defaultValue="password") String password,
            @RequestParam(value="email", required=false, defaultValue="email") String email
            ) throws  Exception {
        Account checkAccount = accountRepository.findByUsername(username);
        System.out.println("checkAccount>>>"+checkAccount);
        if (checkAccount == null) {
            try {               
                // if not create some
                Account newAcc = accountRepository.saveAndFlush(new Account(
                            username, 
                            password, 
                            email
                        ));
                System.out.println("newAcc>>>"+checkAccount);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(newAcc, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("error adding user>>>"+checkAccount);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(e, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        }else{
            // String e = "user exists";
            System.out.println("user already exists>>>"+checkAccount);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(checkAccount, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }   

}
```

Comment: I don't understand much of what you have posted, and I haven't found any question anywhere. What is your question? If your code works fine and you're looking for a code review, then post it to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I don't know how we could answer that question other than by telling "yes, there is a way (and even probably several ways) to implement login handling correctly". That probably won't help you at all. That's why StackOverflow questions should focus on concrete problems.

Comment: No. That's not what StackOverflow is for. Your question is off-topic.

Comment: Its not off topic to show code on a login handling system - and ask for granular discussion on its architecture

Comment: Yes, it is. Of course, I've only been using StackOverflow for almost 7 years on a daily basis, answering thousands of questions, so you probably know better than I do.

Comment: How is showing code for a login handling system, than asking for architecture advice, off topic then. Perhaps spring boot has login handling features I don't know about. Maybe there is a clean way of doing the login/reg process that you may know or could share.

Comment: StackOverflow has a help center discussing all that. It's for precise questions that can be answered by a presise answer. Not for discussions, not for advices, not for code reviews.

Comment: Whatever - I don't agree with you - showing current login functions - and references